# Broadcasting of array

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I was trying to multiply two Numpy array but I am getting broadcasting related error-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-6e9219ae5e45> in <module>
----> 1 d=B*C.reshape(-1,1)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,5,7) (3,1)
```

my arrays are-

```
B=np.random.rand(5,7,3).T.swapaxes(2,1)
C=np.linspace(1,5,3)
d=B*C.reshape(-1,1)
```

Can you please explain what kind of error is this and what I am supposed to do?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to changing the shape of your `C` array from `(3,1)` to `(3, 1, 1)`.

```
B=np.random.rand(5,7,3).T.swapaxes(2,1)
C=np.linspace(1,5,3)
d=B*C.reshape(-1,1, 1)
```